# App crashes when defining cursor position with editText.setSelection(position);

Tags: java, android

The goal is to set cursor position of an *EditText* to 2, using `setSelection(int)`.
Here's the excerpt from my **`RegisterActivity.java`**:

```
 UserEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_email);
 UserEmail.setSelection(2); //cursor position
```

Here's the **`activity_register.xml`**:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/register_email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:background="@drawable/ab_transparent_example"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_mail_outline_gray_24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="17dp"/>
```

The app crashes when I use an `int > 0` in `setSelection(int)`, such as 2 in the code above.

Is there an alternative to that method in the java file?
Is there a workaround inside the xml itself?

Comment: *`App crashes when defining cursor position...`* Where is your Crash Log, you need to share it with question mean while Have a look **[Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your edittext is empty, it will crash because you are trying to set the cursor at a position greater than the length of the string inside the edittext.

First, make sure the string inside has a greater length than the position.

## Example:

```
String text = yourEditText.getText().toString();

if (desirablePosition < text.length()){
  yourEditText.setSelection(desirablePosition);
}
```

Comment: Got it. Is there a way to define the position of an empty EditText, then?

Comment: @TheTourist on an empty EditText, use setSelection(0), otherwise it will crash.

Comment: Ok. Since it's an email field, I need it to be empty when the app starts; perhaps filled only by a hint in the xml, such as "example@gmail.com". The problem I'm facing is that the cursor is right after the email icon drawable, making the spacing poor. What would you suggest to fix this?

Comment: @TheTourist instead of messing with the selection, I would suggest finding a way to set the margin of the drawable.

Comment: Yes, that seems reasonable. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @TheTourist also note, that even if you were able somehow to set the selection itself further away from the drawable, when the user starts typing, the text would still be too close to the drawable, so the margin suggestion from the comment above is a way better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Set default text to the edit text which is greater than 2.. to work set selection > 0, your edit text should have content.